# Referenciar ou embutir documentos no mongodb e no couchdb

Tags: json, mongodb, couchdb

Estou a pensar criar documentos referenciados em vez de embutidos pois tenho uma base de dados em que um avião tem voos e voos têm aeroportos. Alguém experiente que me pudesse indicar a melhor opção?

Imaginemos que opto pelos referenciados, a referencia seria a chave estrangeira numa base de dados relacional ou seja bastava exportar o documento JSON do mysql com as chaves secundarias e apenas carregar para as coleções certo? as referencias não estão necessariamente ligadas no sistema, é só um id que ali está caso seja necessário uma consulta pelo que percebi certo? Como o meu objetivo é um estudo comparativo com o mysql tenho de fazer consultas semelhantes e tirar tempos mas já vi que com documentos referenciados tinha de fazer mais do que uma consulta, é assim mesmo?

Em relação aos embutidos já pesquisei e não consigo entender como vou carregar diferentes JSON e apontar que aquele está contido dentro de outro.

Isto para o mongodb. Em relação ao couchdb alguém tem noção como é feita esta referencia entre coleções? pelo que li não é assim tão trivial como no mongodb.

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?

Answer (score -1):

Viva,

no couchdb não existe a noção de colecções como no mongodb. No couchdb terás de criar 1 db por cada mongodb collection.

ex.: MongoDB

```
db_x
|- collection_01
|- collection_02
```

No CouchDB eu uso prefixos:

```
db_x_collection_01
db_x_collection_02
```

Ou algo assim.

Em relação aos docs embutidos, essa é uma questão que não tem respostas certas.
Tudo vai depender de como os seus dados irão ser consumidos. Essa é a melhor dica que posso dar.

Se há muitas querys à db que precisa de todos os docs, o melhor é embutir,
se o mais frequente, é pedir o doc A e de vez em quando o `doc A->1`, então pode referênciar, sabendo que o couchdb permite o `fetch` de n docs em simultâneo.

Espero ter ajudado.